# No such file or directory (os error 2), stat for rendering public files in oak

Tags: ejs, deno, oak

I am trying out Deno (v1.16.4) with Oak (v10) and ejs for the first time. The tailwind file is just a regular CSS file, so no installs. I got stuck serving a static CSS file. I must be overlooking something.

When I go to `localhost:8080/tailwind.css`, it'll show the file contents, but when going to `localhost:8080/admin`, it won't show `No such file or directory (os error 2), stat '/Users/XXXXXXXX/Documents/projectNameHere/public/admin'`. I've tried adjusting `root` and removing "/public" but now the tailwind file or the html files aren't found.

However, it doesn't seem to be ejs files because removing the first `app.use()` will display the admin pages (without styles, of course). So those are working.

This is the `app.js` for app entry.

```
import { Application } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import { route_home } from "./routes/home.js";
import { route_login } from "./routes/login.js";
import { route_admin } from "./routes/admin.js";
import { route_project } from "./routes/projectSingle.js";
import { route_about } from "./routes/about.js";
import { route_404 } from "./routes/404.js";

const app = new Application();
const port = 8080;

app.use(async (ctx) => {
  console.log(ctx.request.url.pathname);
  await send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
    root: `${Deno.cwd()}/public`,
  });
});
app.use(route_home.routes());
app.use(route_login.routes());
app.use(route_admin.routes());
app.use(route_project.routes());
app.use(route_about.routes());
app.use(route_404.routes());

await app.listen({ port: port });
```

This is the `admin.js` for Admin routes.

```
import { Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import { renderFile } from "https://deno.land/x/dejs@0.10.2/mod.ts";

const router = new Router();

export const route_admin = router
  .get("/admin", async (ctx) => {
    console.log(ctx);
    const body = renderFile(Deno.cwd() + "/views/adminDashboard.ejs");
    ctx.response.body = await body;
  })
  .get("/admin/project-list", async (ctx) => {
    const body = renderFile(Deno.cwd() + "/views/adminProjectsList.ejs");
    ctx.response.body = await body;
  })
  .get("/admin/project/:id", async (ctx) => {
    const body = renderFile(Deno.cwd() + "/views/adminProjectSingle.ejs");
    ctx.response.body = await body;
  })
  .get("/admin/edit-other-pages", async (ctx) => {
    const body = renderFile(Deno.cwd() + "/views/adminOtherPages.ejs");
    ctx.response.body = await body;
  })
  .get("/admin/user-account", async (ctx) => {
    const body = renderFile(Deno.cwd() + "/views/adminUserAccount.ejs");
    ctx.response.body = await body;
  });
```

Any thoughts?

### Updated Code

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  try {
    const dirPath = `${Deno.cwd()}/public`;
    if (existsSync(dirPath)) {
      console.log("yes, dir exists");
      for await (const file of Deno.readDir(dirPath)) {
        console.log("file: ", file);
      }
      await send(ctx, ctx.request.url.pathname, {
        root: `${Deno.cwd()}/public`,
      });
    }

    await next();
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error: ", error);
  }
});
```

file structure:

- app.js
- views

  - index.ejs
  - long list of other views continues...
- routes

  - home.js
  - list of other routes continues...
- public

  - tailwind.css
  - imagesForHomePage

    - googleLogo.png
- models

  - pages.js
  - list of other models continues...

this now gives me the following error:

```
[uncaught application error]: Http - error from user's HttpBody stream: body write aborted

    at async HttpConn.nextRequest (deno:ext/http/01_http.js:67:23)
    at async serve (https://deno.land/x/oak@v10.1.0/http_server_native.ts:237:34)
[uncaught application error]: Http - error from user's HttpBody stream: body write aborted
```

and in the chrome console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll give it a try!
I think your first middleware will try to serve static files on any request. You need a way to distinguish your static files from the rest of your app. For instance, you could try to put your tailwind find at `/public/tailwind.css` instead of `tailwind.css`. Then you can rewrite your middleware this way:

```
app.use(async (ctx, next) => {
  if (ctx.request.url.pathname.startsWith('/public')) {
    const filename = ctx.request.url.pathname.substring(7)
    await send(ctx, filename, { root: 'public'})
  } else {
    await next()
  }
})
```

This implementation checks that the file should be served as static, then serves it without the prefix (otherwise it would try to find `/public/public/tailwind.css`), but other wise you need to call next to pass to the next middleware, here the routers middlewares

Comment: Thanks, Martin. I have the tailwind file in another folder ("public"). For some reason still not working.

Comment: I've even did a for loop and `Deno.readDir("public")` to read the files sent. And the loop does console.log the tailwind.css file. With the app.use() containing the `send()` method it now shows the tailwind.css file contents in the HTML.

Comment: Hello zachary, can you post the new version of your code so I can help you? :)

Comment: Hi Martin, I stepped away from the issue to continue onto other things. Now, I've come back to it. I've totally removed the app.use() to serve the static file. How would you go about it? It feels I've tried multiple things and still not getting the desired outcome. Solutions have either been `NotFoundError - No such file or directory (os error 2), stat`

Comment: What I pointed out in my answer is that your middleware will catch all requests and try to serve the static file corresponding to the URL The request to /admin will not arrive to the router because you never call next() in your middleware, it will try to serve static/admin file My examples shows that you need to check the first part of the URL, serve the static file if it is one, or call next to propagate the request to the 'ext middleware : the router

Comment: so I changed the code to deal with calling next with await (see edit to original post above). I'm getting a new error that I've tried to research but with little success.

Comment: You are testing that your public directory exists, and that will always be true. What you are not testing is that the request url starts with `/public`:
- If URL starts with public : try to send public file
- Else : call next to send request to your admin router

Comment: Martin your answer is correct. I wasn't using `await next()` to call the next middleware. However, what you said worked whenever I also stopped using EJS as a templating engine. For some reason, the adapter wasn't working either. So I've added `await next()` and removed the EJS templating engine. Instead I'm just doing template strings - It's a smaller project so not worried about it. Thank you very much Martin for helping me work through this!

Comment: Great to hear !